# Orientation of the Space of Self-Dual Forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, orientation, gauge-theory

Let $X$ be a closed, orientable, smooth 4-manifold. Let us give an orientation to $X$ by setting $e^1, e^2, e^3, e^4$ to be an *oriented* local orthonormal basis for its cotangent bundle.

Does this induce an orientation on the space of self-dual forms $\Omega^2_+X$? How about $\mathcal{H}^2_+(X)$, the harmonic self-dual forms?

The question is motivated by understanding the Seiberg-Witten invariants. In particular, to orient the moduli space of solutions we need an orientation of the spaces $H^0(X;i\mathbb{R}), H^1(X;i\mathbb{R})$, and $H^2_+(X;i\mathbb{R})$.
I am trying to understand which orientations we get for free from an orientation of $X$ and which we don't. For example, $H^0(X;i\mathbb{R})$ is oriented by the cohomology class $1$ after multiplication by $i$. I think $H^1(X;i\mathbb{R})\cong\mathcal{H}^1(X)$ is oriented for free because we have an orientation of the 1-forms.

Comment: This is a very stupid remark: isn't $\Omega^2X$ an infinite-dimensional vector space in general? Self-dual forms are a subspace of this, but still.

I feel more optimistic about harmonic 2-forms and cohomology groups as they form a finite-dimensional vector space, and I'm pretty sure that an orientation on a vector space $V$ induces one on all $\Lambda^k V$, but I'd have to check.

Comment: This is a good remark. I think we orient the space of 2-forms as a bundle, while the harmonic forms and cohomology as finite dimensional vector spaces. So the space of 2-forms is orientable in the sense that we can make a continuous choice of orientation for each fiber. The continuity condition implies that if we choose an orientation in a single fiber we automatically choose one to every fiber (assuming base is connected). Each fiber is a finite dimensional vector space so this makes sense.